# How to sort a list of entities once per custom sort function in the right order?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Given a bunch of ( not sorted ) entities

```
const entities = [
  { id: "person-1", type: "person", fields: { age: 34 }}, 
  { id: "car-2", type: "car", fields: { manufacturer: "bar" }}, 
  { id: "house-2", type: "house", fields: { constructionYear: 2010 }}, 
  { id: "person-4", type: "person", fields: { age: 71 }},
  { id: "person-2", type: "person", fields: { age: 57 }}, 
  { id: "house-1", type: "house", fields: { constructionYear: 1968 }}, 
  { id: "car-1", type: "car", fields: { manufacturer: "foo" }},
  { id: "person-3", type: "person", fields: { age: 42 }},
];
```

and a bunch of "sources" with an optional sort object describing the sort index and a "isLessThan" compare function as a string

```
const sources = [
  { type: "person", sort: { index: 1, isLessThanFunctionAsString: "(left, right) => left.fields.age < right.fields.age" }},
  { type: "car" },
  { type: "house", sort: { index: 0, isLessThanFunctionAsString: "(left, right) => left.fields.constructionYear < right.fields.constructionYear" }},
];
```

*Each source describes how to deal with entities of the given type. The source for "person" defines how entities of type "person" should be sorted.*

*I do not have any control over the configuration, the `isLessThan` function comes as a stringified function and its signature is `(leftEntity: Entity, rightEntity: Entity) => boolean`, so the logic inside the compare function could be anything*

I want to sort the array `entities` by the information gathered from `sources` and started with

```js
const entities = [{id:"person-1",type:"person",fields:{age:34}},{id:"car-2",type:"car",fields:{manufacturer:"bar"}},{id:"house-2",type:"house",fields:{constructionYear:2010}},{id:"person-4",type:"person",fields:{age:71}},{id:"person-2",type:"person",fields:{age:57}},{id:"house-1",type:"house",fields:{constructionYear:1968}},{id:"car-1",type:"car",fields:{manufacturer:"foo"}},{id:"person-3",type:"person",fields:{age:42}}];

const sources = [{type:"person",sort:{index:1,isLessThanFunctionAsString:"(left, right) => left.fields.age < right.fields.age"}},{type:"car"},{type:"house",sort:{index:0,isLessThanFunctionAsString:"(left, right) => left.fields.constructionYear < right.fields.constructionYear"}}];

function sortEntities(unsortedEntities, allSources) {
  // if there are no entities, there is nothing to do
  if (unsortedEntities.length === 0) {
    return unsortedEntities;
  }

  // only care for the sources with a sort function
  const sourcesWithSort = allSources.filter(source => !!source.sort);

  // if there are no sources with sort, there is nothing to do
  if (sourcesWithSort.length === 0) {
    return unsortedEntities;
  }

  // since we can only compare two entities of the same type we must sort the entities by type first
  let sortedEntities = entities.sort((leftEntity, rightEntity) => {
    // no need for sorting if both have the same type
    if (leftEntity.type === rightEntity.type) {
      return 0;
    }

    if (leftEntity.type < rightEntity.type) {
      return -1;
    }

    return 1;
  });

  // we must sort the sources by sort index ( at this point we now that sort must exist )
  const sortSources = sourcesWithSort.sort((leftSource, rightSource) => leftSource.sort.index - rightSource.sort.index);

  // NOW we can start sorting the entities
  for (const source of sortSources) {
    sortedEntities = sortedEntities.sort((leftEntity, rightEntity) => {
      const {
        type
      } = source;

      // we can't compare entities if the types aren't equal to the source type
      if (leftEntity.type !== type || rightEntity.type !== type) {
        return 0;
      }

      const isLessThanFunction = (new Function("return " + source.sort.isLessThanFunctionAsString))();
      const isLeftEntityLessThanRightEntity = isLessThanFunction(
        leftEntity,
        rightEntity
      );

      if (isLeftEntityLessThanRightEntity) {
        return -1;
      }

      return 1;
    });
  }

  return sortedEntities;
}

console.log(sortEntities([...entities], [...sources]));
```

My approach is getting really slow when dealing with many entities ( > 100 ) and many sources ( > 20 )

Do you have any ideas how to improve the code or maybe come up with faster alternatives?

Comment: What is the expected output? Is it same as whatever the snippet is outputting?

Comment: yes :) A sorted copy of `entities`

Comment: Does the order between entities matter? Like why is `car` at the top of your output when it is not a the top in `columns` or `entities` array. Also, the `isLessThan` functions is something you have created or you don't have control over this? Because `(left, right) => left.fields.age - right.fields.age` is much more appropriate than using `>` for sorting

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your table looks like? How are your types columns, but they have their own fields?

Comment: @adiga no, the order between entity types doesn't matter. `isLessThan` is a function coming from a configuration file, I don't have control over it but I kept the sample as simple as possible

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I updated my question to get rid of the table. The problem has nothing to do with ui elements :) Just plain data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `columns` array to use a comparator function which directly returns a sort order expected buy the sort comapreFn callback function. For the numerical fields it will be subtraction.

```
const columns = [
  { type: "person", sort: { index: 1, comparator: (left, right) => left.fields.age - right.fields.age }},
  { type: "car", sort: undefined },
  { type: "house", sort: { index: 0, comparator: (left, right) => left.fields.constructionYear - right.fields.constructionYear }},
];
```

If you want one for car, it would be

```js
comparator: (a, b) => a.fields.manufacturer.localeCompare(b.fields.manufacturer)
```

Then you create a mapper object which maps the `type` to the `index` and the `comparator` function. If an index is not mentioned, then it is set to `-Infinity` (Because, in your case you have the `car` results on top)

```
const columnMap = columns.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const { type, sort: { index = -Infinity, comparator } = {} } = o
  acc[type] = { index, comparator };
  return acc
}, {})
```

It creates this object:

```
{
  "person": {
    "index": 1,
    "comparator": (a,b)=>a.fields.age-b.fields.age
  },
  "car": {
    "index": -Infinity,
    "comparator": undefined
  },
  "house": {
    "index": 0,
    "comparator": (a,b)=>a.fields.constructionYear-b.fields.constructionYear
  }
}
```

- Then sort the entities based on `index` value
- if the index values are same (or both are -Infinity), then sort based on the `type` name
- if both types are same, then sort based on the type specific `comparator` function.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
const entities=[{id:"person-1",type:"person",fields:{age:34}},{id:"car-2",type:"car",fields:{manufacturer:"bar"}},{id:"house-2",type:"house",fields:{constructionYear:2010}},{id:"person-4",type:"person",fields:{age:71}},{id:"person-2",type:"person",fields:{age:57}},{id:"house-1",type:"house",fields:{constructionYear:1968}},{id:"car-1",type:"car",fields:{manufacturer:"foo"}},{id:"person-3",type:"person",fields:{age:42}}],
      columns=[{type:"person",sort:{index:1,comparator:(e,s)=>e.fields.age-s.fields.age}},{type:"car",sort:void 0},{type:"house",sort:{index:0,comparator:(e,s)=>e.fields.constructionYear-s.fields.constructionYear}}];

function sortEntities(array, columns) {
  const columnMap = columns.reduce((acc, o) => {
    const { type, sort: { index = -Infinity, comparator } = {} } = o
    acc[type] = { index, comparator };
    return acc
  }, {})
  
 return array.sort((a,b) => 
   columnMap[a.type].index - columnMap[b.type].index 
    || a.type.localeCompare(b.type)
    || columnMap[a.type].comparator?.(a,b)
  )
}

console.log(sortEntities(entities, columns))
```

---

If you can't change the `columns` array, you can create your own comparator function by using `eval` to create a function using the string.

```js
const entities=[{id:"person-1",type:"person",fields:{age:34}},{id:"car-2",type:"car",fields:{manufacturer:"bar"}},{id:"house-2",type:"house",fields:{constructionYear:2010}},{id:"person-4",type:"person",fields:{age:71}},{id:"person-2",type:"person",fields:{age:57}},{id:"house-1",type:"house",fields:{constructionYear:1968}},{id:"car-1",type:"car",fields:{manufacturer:"foo"}},{id:"person-3",type:"person",fields:{age:42}}],
      columns =[{type:"person",sort:{index:1,isLessThanFunctionAsString:"(left, right) => left.fields.age < right.fields.age"}},{type:"car"},{type:"house",sort:{index:0,isLessThanFunctionAsString:"(left, right) => left.fields.constructionYear < right.fields.constructionYear"}}];
      
function sortEntities(array, columns) {
  const columnMap = columns.reduce((acc, { type, sort }) => {
    let index = -Infinity, comparator;

    if (sort) {
      eval("var isLessThanFunction =" + sort.isLessThanFunctionAsString)
      index = sort.index;
      comparator = (a, b) => isLessThanFunction(a, b) ? -1 : 1
    }

    acc[type] = { index, comparator };
    return acc
  }, {})

  return array.sort((a, b) =>
    columnMap[a.type].index - columnMap[b.type].index 
    || a.type.localeCompare(b.type) 
    || columnMap[a.type].comparator?.(a, b)
  )
}

console.log(sortEntities(entities, columns))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my late response. I changed my question to simplify the problem a little bit

Comment: @baitendbidz I've added a snippet at the end which uses `isLessThan` property to sort

Comment: I updated my question to show that those compare functions are strings coming from a configuration file. Things like `localeCompare` won't work anymore

Comment: @baitendbidz that's a completely different question altogether. If you log the function that is created, it will be like `function () { (left, right) => ... }`. The argument is used as a body of the new function. So, replace the `const isLessThanFunction = new Function`  line with ` eval("var isLessThanFunction =" + source.sort.isLessThanFunctionAsString);`

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, I fixed the code. As already described in the question, I don't have any control over the configured function strings ( that's why I changed them to strings now ) Do you think your approach is still possible with some adjustments?

Comment: @baitendbidz as mentioned in the previous comment, you need to create the  function using `eval("var isLessThanFunction =" + source.sort.isLessThanFunctionAsString);`. I've updated the snippet

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to make sure your data is prepared to go into a table. You will need to process the raw data and convert it into an array of records. After that, you can sort your data much easier. Lastly, you can convert the sorted records into a table and add it to the document.

Also, you have a key on your sorter called `isLessThan`. You should change that to something more generic like `fn` or `callback`. You will want all sorters to be keyed similarly.

```js
const main = () => {
  document.body.append(table(sort(process(entities), columns), columns));
};

const sort = (data, columns) => {
  const sorters = columns
    .map(({ sort }) => sort)
    .filter(s => s)
    .sort(({ index: a }, { index: b }) => a - b)
    .map(({ isLessThan }) => isLessThan); // This is not good...
  return data.sort((a, b) => {
    let sorted = 0, index = 0;
    while (sorted === 0 && index < sorters.length) {
      sorted = sorters[index](a, b);
      index++;
    }
    return sorted;
  });
};

const process = (rawData) =>
  Object.entries(rawData.reduce((acc, { id, type, fields }) => {
    const [, index] = id.match(/\w+-(\d+)/);
    if (!acc[index]) acc[index] = { id: +index };
    acc[index][type] = { fields };
    return acc;
  }, {})).sort(([k1], [k2]) => k1 - k2).map(([, v]) => v);

const table = (records, columns) =>
  group('table', {},
    group('thead', {},
      group('tr', {},
        ...columns.map(col =>
          leaf('th', { innerText: col.type })
        )
      )
    ),
    group('tbody', {},
      ...records.map(record =>
        group('tr', {},
          ...columns.map(col =>
            leaf('td', {
              innerText: render(record[col.type], record, col)
            })
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

const render = (data, record, column) =>
  data ? JSON.stringify(data) : '';

const leaf = (tagName, options) =>
  Object.assign(document.createElement(tagName), options);

const group = (tagName, options, ...children) =>
  appendAll(leaf(tagName, options), children);

const appendAll = (el, children = []) => {
  children.forEach(child => el.appendChild(child));
  return el;
};

const entities = [
  { id: "person-1", type: "person", fields: { age: 34 }}, 
  { id: "car-2", type: "car", fields: { manufacturer: "bar" }}, 
  { id: "house-2", type: "house", fields: { constructionYear: 2010 }}, 
  { id: "person-4", type: "person", fields: { age: 71 }},
  { id: "person-2", type: "person", fields: { age: 57 }}, 
  { id: "house-1", type: "house", fields: { constructionYear: 1968 }}, 
  { id: "car-1", type: "car", fields: { manufacturer: "foo" }},
  { id: "person-3", type: "person", fields: { age: 42 }},
];

const columns = [
  { type: "id" },
  { type: "person", sort: { index: 1, isLessThan: (left, right) => left?.fields?.age < right?.fields?.age }},
  { type: "car" },
  { type: "house", sort: { index: 0, isLessThan: (left, right) => left?.fields?.constructionYear < right?.fields?.constructionYear }},
];

main();
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table, th, td { border: thin solid grey; }
th, td { padding: 0.5rem; }
th { background: #DDD; }
tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background: #EEE; }
td { font-family: monospace; font-size: smaller; }
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I improved my question, the given data is not ready to be displayed in a table. Maybe this simplifies the problem a little bit